# django registering site with admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

For a given `model` :

```
class SignUp:
   ....
```

I have seen two ways of `registering` the `model` to `admin` in few tutorials.
one is simply using
`admin.site.register(SignUp)`

and other is:

```
class signUpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   class Meta:
       model=SignUp
admin.site.register(SignUp, SignUpAdmin)
```

If I am correct, the second way is handy when we want to customize the `admin` (display, sorted order etc). but if one is not interested in that, then both serve the same purpose correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects):

> ...you can register the model class without providing a ModelAdmin
>   description.

So `admin.site.register(SignUp)` would be the same as,

```
class signUpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(SignUp, signUpAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct.

The first one is the 'out-of-the-box' solution, while the second one is needed when you want to do more fancy stuff (for example editing a model that has a 1 to n relation).